# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - How to show push message in notification area while app is in the foreground

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to show the push message in the notification area when app is up and running in the foreground. Currently when App is in the background (minimized) and a message comes in then it shows in notification area/bar at that time only.

Is this possible to do in Worklight? Or do I have to do some native level change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS - certainly not. There is no ability to extend the OS behavior.

In Android - Android allows for some extending of the code, but I have never seen such an implementation not in Worklight nor in native apps...
When the app is in the background you can display a dialog, add some visual cue in the app itself, but use the notification bar? ...

Comment: there are few Apps that's doing it; like WhatsUp is showing messages in the notification area/bar when App is up & running. I think native level change may help here.

Comment: So you can try extending the code, but as usual such extending is not supported by Worklight...